# No module named kivy in PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, kivy

New to Kivy and PyCharm on Windows. Tried the Pong Game tutorial that was suggested on the Kivy website. Ran into the error displayed in the photo below. Installed Cython using pip as well. I have no clue as to what the problem is here.

[UPDATE]:
Tried the same program on IDLE, works just fine.

[Screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yvgp.jpg)
[image: Screenshot #2]

[UPDATE #2]:
The screenshot above is the most recent picture of what i see on PyCharm.

Comment: Do you have kivy installed?

Comment: Yes i do, i installed it using pip as per the instructions found on https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: It seems that he has not done it correctly.

Comment: which part of his instructions may be wrong?

Comment: check your venv and verify that there is a folder called kivy.

Comment: I just checked the venv folder of the respective project, and you were right. I did not find a kivy file. Can i copy the one that is in my python library site packages folder into the venv folder? Or should i copy the Kivy 1.10.0 folder?

Comment: Try placing the cursor in the kivy text that is in red and press Ctrl + Enter

Comment: Referring to the second screenshot i have uploaded, there is no longer the kivy text in red. I have tried adding the kivy folders into the venv folder. Do let me know if what i have done is correct. Thank you

Comment: Thats the problem. In idle it works fine but in pycharm it gives error.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install `kivy` manually on `pycharm`, follow these six steps:

1. Click on Files on top left corner.
2. Click on settings.
3. Click on Project and click on project interpreter.
4. Click on (➕) icon on right.
5. Click on "Search" and type "Kivy" you will find a lot of packages, then choose Kivy and 
   install it.
6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Usually PyCharm will complain in the editor with red squigglies underlining `import kivy` if it is not installed. I am not sure why it is not in your case. Perhaps your run configuration is using a different interpreter than the one used by the project for autocompletion and such. Click on the drop down at the top right, near the run button. Then click on Edit Configuration.... Make sure the interpreter is set to the project's default.

To install kivy in you venv from the command line,  first activate it with

```
. /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

Then run pip commands as usual.

Comment: How may I install kivy with the venv folder? Do i change the directory to the venv folder when i am downloading kivy with pip using Command Prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I have just succeeded with

```
pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
```

But not with

```
pip install kivy
```

https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html

Running OS X, PyCharm 2018.1, pipenv, Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Change project interpreter to system interpreter
file > setting > project > project interpreter > gear icon > system interpretor